# How modify url request for NSURLCache

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I'm using AFNetworking, making API calls that respond with proper cache-control headers.
Everything works fine with requests honoring the cache except for one glitch.

The API I'm using requires a signature to be created with a lifetime of 5 minutes. It's generated from the current time, API key, and API secret. So when I pass this in as a sig parameter, the cache is going to continually miss.

Example:

```
request1: http://foo.com?p=hello&apikey=12345&sig=ABCDEF

request2: http://foo.com?p=hello&apikey=12345&sig=ZYXWVU
```

So request 2 is a cache miss.

Question: How could I modify the request in such a way as to strip out the signature parameter for caching only?